# how to add scroller for one div, 2 divs always visible

Tags: html, css, layout

Im creating HTML layout: 3 horizontal layers. Layers 1&2 from top, they should have constant height (ex. 100px), and these 2 layeres should be always visible.

3rd layer should take the rest of screen in height. But 3rd layout should have scroller to scroll down&up if content takes more the space left under layer1&2.

I created a code but scroler is for the whole page. How to create scroller only last bottom widest layer (div)?

[Current code](http://jsfiddle.net/kL3gugur/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="layer1">
            Layer 1
        </div>

        <div id="layer2">
            Layer 2 </br>
Layer 2 </br>Layer 2 </br>Layer 2 </br>Layer 2 

        </div>
            <div id="Div3">
                Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>    Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>    Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>
    Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>Layer 3 </br>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#layer1 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
}

#layer2 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;   
}

#layer3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: calc(100% - (120px));
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

UPDATE 1)
Maybe this is not clear from my description, but bottom div should take no more that the viewport. And div 1 and div 2 (from top) should be always visible.

Comment: Your div3 id is incorrect

Comment: I know thi is not working:)... what is the solution of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht7e7mgh/)

You can use;

```
height: 160px;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Comment: almost good, but last layer should take the rest of page, but there is some white space under div3

Comment: when I change the size of screen, white field is displayed at the bottom

Comment: Looks good in jsFiddler, but not in real browser. In real browser: div 1&2 are no displayed always, scroller works for div1,2,3 but it should work only for div3

Answer (score 1):

Your code was good just change

```
<div id="Div3">
```

to

```
<div id="layer3">
```

And some modification here

```
#layer3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;//just reference
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 120px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 120px);
    height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

just another change try 100vh instead of 100% its work like charm..:)

Comment: Yes;) looks better.  But I want the last div to take no more space than viewport,  te scroller should work for div3 only. Div1&2 should be always vdisplayed.

Comment: in your fiddle you didn't change `<div id="Div3">` to `<div id="layer3">'.

Comment: great hope i helped you :)

Comment: Yes, still it need some work with joining this with existing app, but this is other story. Thanks